# Can we worship the Brahman as "Tadvana?

Tags: gods, worship, brahman, kena-upanishad

From [this](http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/brahma/brahma_07.html) link,***Taddha tadvanam nama tadvanam iti upasitavyam
(Kena Upanishad)***

> Meaning-"That is Adorable(Tadvanam); one should meditate on It as 'Adorable'."
>   This is one Upanishadic meditation, in the Kena Upanishad. Brahman is
>   the most adorable and we should conceive Brahman as the most adorable
>   and you will become the most adorable in the world.

So,is "Tadvanam" a name for Brahman who is beyond description and by this name can we worship the Brahman like we worship other deities?.

Comment: Who voted to close this one?May i know his reasons?I'm quite specific about the question.Any Deity who has a name CAN BE worshiped whereas one without a name CAN NEVER BE.So ,if this verse is suggesting that "Tadvanam" is the name of Brahman,then "can he be worshiped by that name?" is my question which is quite simple and specific.

Comment: First, Brahman is not a deity like other deities. Second, you cannot worship the Nirguna Brahman. You can only worship the Saguna Brahman. Yes, you can worship Brahman as Tadvana.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda i know that Brahman is not a deity but since that  verse states that we should meditate upon Him as Tadvana,that means we can worship HIm as well by that name,in the same fashion we worship Deities.That was my point.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, is there any reason why you feel that one "cannot worship the *Nirguna Brahman*"? IMHO, it might be quite difficult ([BG 12.5](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/12/5)), but certainly not impossible. In a way I feel that the people who rely completely on science are indirectly the worshipers of *Nirguna Brahman* only. It's like an extreme case of *Neti Neti* school of thoughts. To me, *Nirguna Brahman* can be equated as the ultimate "Nothing". Hence non-believers are equally right in describing "Nothing is God". :-) However, I would be interested to know your viewpoint as well.

Comment: @iammilind There are numerous scriptural references that say so. Nirguna is beyond maya and has no awareness of maya. The awareness of maya is only within maya. When you perceive a mirage in the desert is the desert aware of the mirage? Nirguna Brahman and Saguna Brahman are the same. Brahman seen through the lens of maya is Saguna Brahman. The wave of the ocean is no different than the ocean, the wave simply gives the ocean a perceived form. Likewise Saguna allows us to 'perceive' Brahman. Kena Upanishad 1.5 - "Know that alone to be Brahman, not that which people adore here."

Comment: If the Upanishad mentions it should be done I think that is justification enough to do it :)

Comment: Yes but I was worried about what shd be the proper methods here.. because worshipping Tadvana is not mainstream stuff :).. @Dr.VineetAggarwal

Comment: Yes it sounds closer to the Bhakti tradition where you can think of the Lord as the loved one and worship Him accordingly.